# Connecting E-paper display (GD) to Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, display

I'm still learning how to use Arduino and electrical components, but I will try my best to understand any answers!

So I just bought an e-paper display off a website, not from the manufacturer itself (http://www.good-display.com/products_detail/productId=305.html). The product is a 1.54 inch E-paper display 200x200 partial update GDEP015OC1.

[image: e-paper display]

I was a bit puzzled by how to connect the display to the Arduino Uno. Turns out that to connect the display to a board, it needs a breakout board (is this the correct term?). I could buy it online from the manufacturer, however, it will take me at least a month and the shipping cost is too high.

I was wondering if it is possible for me to make my own breakout board? Is there any 'general' breakout board for an e-paper display, or does it have any special from the manufacturer? If it is possible, how difficult would it be for a beginner who has almost no knowledge on circuit building/electrical components?

The aim is just to display an image onto the e-ink display.

Thanks!

edit: I bought the mentioned display because of the size. I was afraid of not knowing how to connect the mention display (which is where I am now), so I bought this e-ink display also: https://www.smart-prototyping.com/E-ink-E-paper-Display-module-3.3V-2.04-inch-177x72.html I was thinking to take the 60mmx30mm display off the board and try connecting the 30mmx30mm display to the 'breakout board' if I am unable to build my own board. Both seemed to have the same pin number (need to confirm later).

Comment: Hi and welcom to the Arduino SE community. This question is not directly about Arduino. Please take the [tour](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [on topic](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [don't ask](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) help pages.

Comment: This is the E-Ink / Paper display device integrated by the image display technology of Microencapsulated Electrophoretic Display (MED). This device has an approach to create a tiny spheres in which the charge color pigments are suspending the transparent electrode. Wiring to your microcontroller Follow this link [1.52 Inch Epaper](http://www.14core.com/guide-spi-eink-electronic-paper-display-panel/) [Wiring E-Ink/E-Paper with Microcontroller](http://www.14core.com/wiring-the-spi-172x72-gray-shade-electronic-ink-e-ink-module/)

Answer (score 1):

E-ink displays require high voltages to operate them. They are electrostatic devices and the pixels need charging up to a high voltage (high compared to what an Arduino runs at) to attract the pigment powder (basically the same as laser printer toner) to create an image.

While it is possible to make your own board it's not something that is simple and straight forward. Designing boost converters requires a certain base level of knowledge and expertise to get it right. Not something I would recommend a beginner attempting.

Even though a display may have the same pin number as another it doesn't follow that the pins are in the same order on the connector. There is no standard and each display from different manufacturers (and even different displays from the same manufacturer) will have a different pin-out. You will need to compare the datasheets for the two displays to see if the pin-out is the same and if it isn't you would have to somehow map from one to the other on the driver board.

The simplest option is to just order the correct driver board for that display.

(Note: in this context it is called a *driver board* not a *breakout board*. A breakout board is typically a passive circuit board that converts from one hard-to-use connector or footprint to a simpler, say 0.1", header. A driver board contains active electronics, in this case a boost converter, to drive the device it is connected to.)